# Finding the interior and boundary of a subset of $(l^1,||\cdot||_{1})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the folllowing metric space: $X = (l^1,||\cdot||_{1})$. Recall $$l^1 = \big\{\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}: \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_k| < \infty\big\}.$$

Let $Y \subset X$ be the set of sequences $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \in l^1$ such that $x_{2k} = x_{2k-1}, \forall n.$ I want to find the interior and boundary of Y.

$\mathbf{My\,\, attempt}$:

We know that $X = \text{Int}(Y) \sqcup \text{Bd}(Y) \sqcup \text{Int}(Y^C).$ I think $Y^c$ is open , so $Y$ is closed and therefore, $\text{cl}(Y) = Y$. Henceforth, $\text{Bd}(Y) = Y$ and $ \text{Int}(Y) = \emptyset$ (since $\text{cl}(Y) = \text{Int}(Y) \sqcup \text{Bd}(Y)$ and we know $Y$ is closed).

I want to know if I'm on the right track and if yes, how can I prove rigorously that for any $y_0 \in Y^c,$ there exists an $\varepsilon$- ball $B(y_0, \varepsilon)$ that lies completely inside $Y^c$ (or in other words, $Y^c$ is open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not prove that the interior is empty. Just because $Y$ is closed you cannot say that the boundary is $Y$ and interior is empty.

$Y^{c}$ is open: If $(x_n) \notin Y$ there exist $k$ such that $x_{2k}\neq x_{2k-1}$. Let $\epsilon =|x_{2k}- x_{2k-1}|$. If $(y_k) \in B((x_k),\epsilon /2)$ then $y_{2k} \neq y_{2k-1}$ so $(y_n) \notin Y$: For this use the inequality $|x_{2k}- x_{2k-1}| \leq |y_{2k}- y_{2k-1}|+|x_{2k}- y_{2k}|+|x_{2k-1}- y_{2k-1}|$ and note that the second and third term are less then $\epsilon /2$.

$Y$ is a subspace of $\ell^{1}$ and no proper subspace can have any interior points. [Suppose $B(y_0,\epsilon) \subseteq Y$. Let $y \in X$ and choose $N$ such that $\frac  {\|y\|} N <\epsilon$. Then $y_0 \in Y$ and $\frac y N+y_0 \in B(y_0,\epsilon) \subseteq Y$. Sinec $Y$ is  a subspace it folows that $y =N(\frac y N+y_0)-Ny_0 \in Y$. This proves that $Y=X$].  This proves that the interior is empty and the boundary is $Y$.